# Using SQL intersect query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-spatial

I am trying to find the length of a polyline inside a polygon using this query:

```
DECLARE @p geometry, @l geometry;

SELECT @l = SHAPE FROM [Vz_DSM_Stationing].[dbo].[Route_Sections] WHERE OBJECTID = 3;
SELECT @p = SHAPE FROM [Vz_DSM_Extra].[dbo].[PERMIT_BOUNDARIES] WHERE OBJECTID = 8;

SELECT @p.STIntersection(@l).STLength();
```

This query retrieves the shapes correctly, but selects NULL at the final statement.

Comment: are both geometries in the same CRS?

Comment: Yes they are both in 'NAD_1983_StatePlane_Iowa_South_FIPS_1402_Feet'

Comment: Did you try `select @l.STIntersection(@p).STLength();` ?

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work either.

Comment: What are the Linestring coordinates after STIntersection?

Comment: They are the same as they were before.

Comment: Add SELECT @l.STSrid; SELECT @p.STSrid; statements to make sure CRS-es match. STLength() is so permissive function so it even lets invalid geometries as input giving 0 as output. A question: do you get NULL from STIntersection() or from STLength() ?